# change hinge loss error function with cross-entropy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, neural-networks, softmax, cross-entropy

I'm trying to implement cross-entropy as an error function in RBF neural networks instead of hinge loss error function. I need to find cross-entropy error for each output neuron, like hinge loss error function as you can see in the formula below

[image]

but when it comes to cross-entropy, it seems meaningless. because the formulation of cross-entropy returns 1 scaler. I look at some of the recent papers using cross-entropy and soft-max but can't find any relative information to my problem.

Is there any way to finding cross-entropy value for each neuron of output?

Comment: The given hinge loss formula also returns a single scalar. What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: @jkm assume `n` as the number of Classes so output layer has `n` output neuron. in the formula, I previously mentioned the `j` index, points output neurons and as you can see the formula calculate the error for each neuron. the output of equation is a vector $ {e_1, e_2 ,...e_n}$. the problem is I can't find any same formula for each output neuron when I use cross-entropy.

Comment: ...just substitute the two conditional formulas in the bracket with a single standard cross-entropy formula over each j?

Comment: @jkm if I do so, it becomes meaningless because in the first condition of formula the multiplication must be more than one. but in cross-entropy, we use soft-max which is the normal distribution. assume that we change the first condition, the formula of cross-entropy is $-\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_j \log{\widehat{y}_j^~}$ . in this formula just one term of `sum` have to value cause $y_j$ is a vector with just an element with the value of one. so it seems meaningless to me if separate the error of each neuron. maybe I don't get correctly waht you exactly mentioned.

Comment: @jkm do you mean using something like this : $\begin{cases}0 & y_j*\widehat{y}_j > 1\\z_j-y_j & other\end{cases}$ assume that `z` is softmax function ?

Comment: Just remove the condition. You don't need it. It's just a part of the definition of hinge loss - it conditionally clips the loss. And that xent formula is either for multidimensional features or for estimating total loss.

Comment: @jkm I can't figure out what you mean by cross-entropy for each neuron. assume we have [0,1,0] as target vector for data i and the output of the neural network is [0.3,0.4,0.3] so what is the cross-entropy value for each output neuron? 
as cross-entropy said it must be err=0*log0.3 + 1*log 0.4 + 0* log 0.3 
and the output of cross-entropy as calculate above is scaler .
can you please explain it more?